# Установить значение переменной от ...

Tags: html, javascript

Есть такой код http://jsfiddle.net/Akt85/ нужно что бы в поле инпут вбивалось любое число например от 5 и до бесконечности т.е. что нужно написать в значение val2? И такой вопрос - можно ли в val1:91 в строчке ниже перечислить сразу несколько значений т.е. писать не так

```
{name:"data2",val1:91,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},
{name:"data2",val1:181,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},
{name:"data2",val1:31,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},
```

а например

```
{name:"data2",val1:91;31;181,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},
```

Comment: Написать-то можно:

    {name:"data2",val1:[91,31,181],val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},

только это же входные данные, которые у вас приходят откуда-то? или вы их жестко прошиваете?

Вообще фильтры строятся на основании схемы данных, где есть описания типов полей и видов виджетов, которые будут использоваться для каждого из полей (инпут, чекбоксы, слайдер и т.д.). Кстати, правильный фильтр выводит все записи, если ни одно значение в фильтре не заполнено...

Answer (score 3):

```
можно ли в val1:91 в строчке ниже перечислить сразу несколько значений
```

Нет, нельзя, т.к. {} - объект, по сути представляющий собой хеш-таблицу из ключей и значений.

Можно поступить чуточку иначе:

```
[{name:"data2"},{val1:91},31,181,{val2:1},{val3:false},{val4:false}]
```

Ну а чтобы в поле `val2` можно было вводить только цифровые значения, лучше всего будет просто добавить информационное поле, прим:

```
document.getElementById('val2').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var ps = parseInt(this.value);

    this.nextSibling.style.display = (ps < 5 || ps != this.value) ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
}, false);
```

Прим: http://jsfiddle.net/UD8cj/

Comment: @lampa, Да, но как написать в этой строке 
{{name:"data1",val1:31,val2:7,val3:true,val4:false},}
 что val2 это любое число?

Comment: @нгш в том то и дело, в никак, потому что в объекте значения и ключи могут быть сколь угодно разными. Я вижу решение таким: добавляем дополнительное свойство, указывающее, какой формат определенной записи и дальше при заполнении значений проверяем скриптом, удовлетворяет ли оно условию из доп. свойства.

Comment: @lampa а можно сделать например так {{ if (val2 > 0)    { return true}  else {return false }

var myvar = [  
    {name:"data1",val1:31,val2:true ,val3:true,val4:false}, }}